# How to do pagination for bootstrap grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-pagination

Here in the above piece of code I succeeded in getting the o/p with table pagination but i'm not getting it for grid pagination.Where It should have only 3 columns and 1 row per a page... I'm not getting the logic please help me... How to do pagination for bootstrap grid? Therefore I deleted table tags and rows and tried to do it by bootstrap grid but i didnt get expected o/p

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#t1').after('<div id="nav" class="text-center"></div>');
  var rowsShown = 3;
  var rowsTotal = $('#t1 row').length;
  var numPages = rowsTotal / rowsShown;
  for (i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
    var pageNum = i + 1;
    $('#nav').append('<a href="#" class="btn-outline-info" rel="' + i + '">&emsp;' + pageNum + '&emsp;</a> ');
  }
  $('#t1 row').hide();
  $('#t1 row').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
  $('#nav a:first').addClass('active');
  $('#nav a').bind('click', function() {
    $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
    var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
    var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
    $('#t1 row').css('opacity', '0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
    css('display', 'table-row').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div classs="t1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `@Manoj`> Why are you using # while `classs="t1"` in you html so you need to replace `Hash(#)` to `Dot(.)` like *$('.t1')* and also you are missing `Dot(.)` in **row** class so it should be like $('.t1 .row') and  change `css('display', 'table-row')` to `css('display', 'flex')`. So Your above js code is working just need to small changes which already i mentioned here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I small changed into you existing JS code so its working as you want so you can check blow snippet.
Changed `css('display', 'table-row')` to `css('display', 'flex')`.
Added `e` in `$('#nav a').bind('click', function(e)` method and this line also `e.preventDefault();` for prevent the hash(#) show in url.
**Note: `Please check on FULL Page`**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.t1').after('<div id="nav" class="text-center"></div>');
  var rowsShown = 3;
  var rowsTotal = $('.t1 .row').length;
  var numPages = rowsTotal / rowsShown;
  for (i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
    var pageNum = i + 1;
    $('#nav').append('<a href="#" class="btn-outline-info" rel="' + i + '">&emsp;' + pageNum + '&emsp;</a> ');
  }
  $('.t1 .row').hide();
  $('.t1 .row').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
  $('#nav a:first').addClass('active');
  $('#nav a').bind('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
    var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
    var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
    $('.t1 .row').css('opacity', '0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
    css('display', 'flex').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="container my-2 t1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="assets\rajetta.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```